# Receive Facebook real time updates into Kafka

Tags: facebook-graph-api, apache-kafka

im pretty new to kafka  and i'm  wondering  if i'm heading in the right direction.

I want to recive Facebook real time update [facebook subscriptions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/app/subscriptions) into kafka .

To get the data back from Facebook you need to provide URL that you will be receiving the data back.

So i figured out the the best way to recive the data is to implement  [dropwizard-kafka-http](https://github.com/stealthly/dropwizard-kafka-http) and push the data into kafka.

- Is it the best way to recive the data or you recomend a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're definitely on the right track.

Note that FB's push notifications will not get you the actual content; you still need to request it. From their docs:

> Note that real-time updates only indicate that a particular field has changed, they do not include the value of those fields. They should be used only to indicate when a new Graph API request to that field needs to be made.

So if you wanted a quick way to get the actual stuff into Kafka, you're out of luck. You're gonna have some minimal back and forth.

Are you sure you want to use Java? How about a lightweight spray-can Endpoint in Scala? After all, Kafka is a Scala project :)